# How to limit access to pv

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

In openshift, PV is available through all projects, and if you can see it, you can claim it.

Is there a way to limit PV only available for certain apps/projects? for others, they are forbidden to use it.

Seems StorageClass does not fit this requirement.

Best regards

Lan

Answer (score 5):

You can pre-bind volume and claim [1]:

> You may also want your cluster administrator to "reserve" the volume for only your claim so that nobody else’s claim can bind to it before yours does. In this case, the administrator can specify the PVC in the PV using the claimRef field. The PV will only be able to bind to a PVC that has the same name and namespace specified in claimRef. The PVC’s access modes and resource requests must still be satisfied in order for the PV and PVC to be bound, though the label selector is ignored.
>
> If you know exactly what PersistentVolume you want your PersistentVolumeClaim to bind to, you can specify the PV in your PVC using the volumeName field. This method skips the normal matching and binding process. The PVC will only be able to bind to a PV that has the same name specified in volumeName. If such a PV with that name exists and is Available, the PV and PVC will be bound regardless of whether the PV satisfies the PVC’s label selector, access modes, and resource requests.

PersistentVolume Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0001
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  nfs:
    path: /tmp
    server: 172.17.0.2
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  claimRef:
    name: claim1
    namespace: default
```

PersistentVolumeClaim example:

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "PersistentVolumeClaim"
metadata:
  name: "claim1"
spec:
  accessModes:
    - "ReadWriteOnce"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "1Gi"
  volumeName: "pv0001"
```

[1] https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/persistent_volumes.html#persistent-volumes-volumes-and-claim-prebinding

Comment: Please mark the answer as a solution if it helped you resolve your issue :)